# jQuery scrolltop for a submit button

Tags: jquery, html

I have a submit button which after submitting a form should scroll to a id. There are other button in the form like next and back which also should scroll to the same id.

**jquery********

```
     jQuery('.scroll').click(function () {
        jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: jQuery('#blog1').offset().top }, 'slow');

        return false;

    });
```

*html************
** next and back button code *************

```
              <input class="send_btn scroll" type="button"  value="Back" />
```

* register button code **********

```
  <input class="send_btn" type="submit" value="Register" />
```

The jquery code is working fine for next and back button. If i add scroll class to register it is scolling to blog1 but the form is not submitting. If i dont add scroll class form is submitting but it is not scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

A jsFiddle would be useful, but you could try this:

```
<input class="send_btn scroll" type="button" value="Register" />
```

Comment: type button will not register the form

Comment: But you can use `.submit()` :)